# Error downloading a csv in zip from website with get in R

Tags: r, download, wget, http-status-code-403

I would like to read data from nse-india.com to R using download.file() as shown below.

```
url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip'
temp = tempfile()
download.file(url, destfile = temp,method = 'wget')
```

It throws up following error:

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\PROGRA~2\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-09-28 21:19:26--  http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip
Resolving www.nseindia.com... 202.83.22.200, 202.83.22.203
Connecting to www.nseindia.com|202.83.22.200|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-09-28 21:19:26 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Warning messages:
1: running command 'wget  "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip" -O "C:\Users\ITITHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2fjADx\file1fb02375882"' had status 1 
2: In download.file(url, destfile = temp, method = "wget") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

Please let me know anyway to fix this.

EDIT: Or any other method to download the file from within R would also be great.

Comment: Try `download.file(..., mode = "wb")`

Comment: Even with `'wb'` mode geting the error.

Comment: Refer `nser` package to download bhavcopy. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a browser-like user agent string so the site thinks you're a browser vs an automated scraper/downloader robot:

```
library(httr) # >=v0.5

GET("http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip",
    user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk("cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip"))

## Response [http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip]
##   Date: 2014-09-28 23:53
##   Status: 200
##   Content-type: application/zip
##   Size: 58.2 kB
## <ON DISK>  cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip
```

Comment: Would it be possible without `httr` library?

Comment: Aye. Look at the source for `GET`, `user_agent` and `write_disk`. Most `httr` calls are just wrappers for `RCurl` (it uses `RCurl` under the covers for pretty much everything). Just type `GET` in the console or poke around at the [github repo](https://github.com/hadley/httr)

Answer (score 0):

You need permission to access that site.  Here is the message (in doc) from the `httr` package:

```
url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip'
doc <- content(GET(url))


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Access Denied</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/SEP/cm24SEP2014bhav.csv.zip" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.df24317.1411924047.3b4f02a1
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can it be? I can download the file in browser, also by DownThemAll !!

Comment: Do you have to log in to the website on your browser to download the data? Anyway, if you can download the file, why not just save it and load it into R from your local copy?

Comment: The site needs no log-in info. I need to use that in a function, also the link can be constructed if using from R.