# Web file download - Return code 403 (Browser & Java Program, mouse click works fine)

Tags: java, http-status-code-403

**Requirement** - Download file from website

**Issue** - The program issues error as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/FEB/cm25FEB2015bhav.csv.zip
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1460)
```

The download works fine if I follow below manual steps:

1. Open browser with link - [weblink](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm)
2. Select ***Bhavcopy*** from Select Report drop down field
3. Specify date as ***25-02-2015*** Click on the file - ***cm25FEB2015bhav.csv.zip***

But if I paste the file path - [link](https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/FEB/cm25FEB2015bhav.csv.zip) directly in the browser, it gives 403 error.

I believe since the download does not work from the browser directly through the link, even my prog is unable to download the same. I tried the suggestions mentioned in the threads - [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser), [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092798/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-403-for-url), [Thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086868/error-downloading-a-csv-in-zip-from-website-with-get-in-r) but did not help.

**Query:** Is there anyway to circumvent this blocking by the server through java code? As I need to download the files for several dates so manual clicking is not possible

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String urlPath = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/FEB/cm25FEB2015bhav.csv.zip";
    URL url = new URL(urlPath);
    // Option - 1:
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    conn.connect();
    // Option - 2:
//        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//        connection.addRequestProperty("REFERER", https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm);
//        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        String zipBhavCopy = "C:\\zipBhavCopy.zip";

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(urlPath), new File(zipBhavCopy));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This web site will check user agent and refer url in a http request.

So you need adding the refer url to your request.

> The HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer[1]) is an HTTP header field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI or IRI) that linked to the resource being requested. By checking the referrer, the new webpage can see where the request originated.

Add this line to your code.

`conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm")`

HTTP server checks this field to prevent from abusing.

Comment: It does not work. I have already tried this, refer to option-2 in the code pasted in my initial query

Comment: I can download it with command `$ curl -v -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" -e "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm" https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/FEB/cm25FEB2015bhav.csv.zip -o temp.zip` .  It seems that user agent and refer are both required.

Comment: It may work with CURL command but it isn't working via the java program. Also I cannot download each file using console commands.